# nopCommerce 2.40 Admin Product - how to Add Product Documents (.pdf, .doc, .vss) in admin section

Tags: nopcommerce

I want to add different types of documents to the product in admin section. I will appreciate if anyone can reply to this.

I found some help here (but it is not working): [nopCommerce 2.40 Admin Product Edit Addition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9791635/nopcommerce-2-40-admin-product-edit-addition)

Answer (score 0):

nopcommerce has not provide any direct way to add documents for products, but you can achieve this by adding "**fileuploader**"  attribute to products.

go to ProductVarientInfo tab in Admin area(Catalog/Products/ManageProducts) in that

ProductVarientInfo -> ProductVarientAttribute

add new attribute with Control type "FileUploader". it will add new attribute to your product where you can upload any type of file.